# C# - How to sort strings that include text and numbers

Tags: c#, sorting, compare, string-comparison, compareto

I have a listview that is filled with computernames and usernames and a number(as string). I already created my own ListViewItemComparer using the IComparer interface. But it doesn´t sort the items correctly like how I want.
This is how it should sort the computers for example:
Computer-1
Computer-2
Computer-3
...
Computer-15

and this is how it sorts them:
Computer-1
Computer-10
Computer-11
...
Computer-2
Computer-3

The problem is that i can´t simply cut the "computer-" part out and compare the numbers that follows as this was just an example and the computernames can be everything(aaa393bbb333, ccccvvvv, 222hhhdh,Computer-01, Computer-02,....)

This is my code:

```
 private bool isNumeric(String pInput)
    {
        int o;
        return int.TryParse(pInput, out o);
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        ListViewItem itemX = x as ListViewItem;
        ListViewItem itemY = y as ListViewItem;
        //
        int returnVal = -1;
        if (itemX == null && itemY == null) returnVal = 0;
        else if (itemX == null) returnVal = -1;
        else if (itemY == null) returnVal = 1;
        else if (itemX.SubItems.Count - 1 < col && itemY.SubItems.Count - 1 < col) returnVal = 0;
        else if (itemX.SubItems.Count - 1 < col) returnVal = -1;
        else if (itemY.SubItems.Count - 1 < col) returnVal = 1;
        else if(isNumeric(itemX.SubItems[col].Text) && isNumeric(itemY.SubItems[col].Text))
        {
            //used for number comparison
            int value1 = int.Parse(itemX.SubItems[col].Text);
            int value2 = int.Parse(itemY.SubItems[col].Text);
            if (value1 == value2) returnVal = 0;
            else if (value1 < value2) returnVal = -1;
            else if (value1 > value2) returnVal = 1;
        }
        else returnVal = String.Compare(itemX.SubItems[col].Text, itemY.SubItems[col].Text);
        if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
            returnVal *= -1;
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Of course you can "cut out" the computer name from the number, just don't forget about them ;-) When comparing two computer names, you first compare the computer name part without the number. If they are different (unequal), then you got the desired comparison result now. If the computer name parts are identical (equal), you will then compare the number parts. So, now you also got the desired comparision result even if the computer name parts where the same...

Comment: There is a "natural sort" method built into windows. File explorer uses it to sort alpha numeric file names

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you didn´t understand me. "Computer-" was only an example of a computername. The computer names can be everything. So a computername can even be this aaaa100aa2. But how would i compare that to other computernames?

Comment: @Disaffected 1070452 yes this is exactly what i am looking for.
But how do i implement that?

Comment: Go to your favorite search engine and research "natural sort"  There are dozens of solutions already here

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex expression

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

to split the string into numbers and text.

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(theString, @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)");
```

This yields alternately numbers and texts. How it works:

```
(?<=exp)pos      Match any position pos following a prefix exp. 
pos(?=exp)       Match any position pos preceding a suffix exp.
```

So the regex means, split at a position between text and number or at a position between number and text where `\D` stands for a non-digit character, `\d` for a digit character and `|` for OR.

You will have to test whether the first part is a text or a number with

```
bool firstIsNumber = Char.IsDigit(parts[0][0]);
```

If the first part is a number, all parts at even indexes are numbers and all parts at odd indexes are texts and vice versa.

```
private static readonly Regex numTextSplitRegex =
    new Regex(@"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    x = x ?? "";
    y = y ?? "";
    string[] xParts = numTextSplitRegex.Split(x);
    string[] yParts = numTextSplitRegex.Split(y);

    bool firstXIsNumber = xParts[0].Length > 0 && Char.IsDigit(xParts[0][0]);
    bool firstYIsNumber = yParts[0].Length > 0 && Char.IsDigit(yParts[0][0]);

    if (firstXIsNumber != firstYIsNumber) {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(xParts.Length, yParts.Length); i++) {
        int result;
        if (firstXIsNumber == (i % 2 == 0)) { // Compare numbers.
            long a = Int64.Parse(xParts[i]);
            long b = Int64.Parse(yParts[i]);
            result = a.CompareTo(b);
        } else { // Compare texts.
            result = xParts[i].CompareTo(yParts[i]);
        }
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return xParts.Length.CompareTo(yParts.Length);
}
```